# Colocar valores percentuais em barras no ggplot

Tags: r

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Gostaria de saber como faço para adicionar os valores percentuais nas barras do gráfico do ggplot. No eixo x consegui adicionar, mas nas barras não.

Gostaria de adicionar no formato de porcentagem mesmo.
O código utilizado foi esse:

```
SP=data.frame(

  Setores=c("Extrativa mineral", "Indústria de transformação", "Serviços Industr de Utilidade Pública", "Construção Civil","Comércio", "Serviços","Adm. Pública", "Agro., extr. vegetal, caça e pesca"),

  Percentual=c(0.005,0.0399,0.001,0.024,0.3234,0.5769,0,0.028)
)

ggplot(SP, aes(x=Setores, y=Percentual)) +

  geom_bar(aes(fill = Setores), stat="identity") + theme_minimal()+

  coord_flip()+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+

  labs(title="Total percentual por setor do trabalho parcial em Minas")
```

Segue a figura que rodei até o momento.

Agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Use o `geom_text` para inserir o texto e a função `percent` do pacote `scales` para fazer a transformação.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

SP=data.frame(

  Setores=c("Extrativa mineral", "Indústria de transformação", "Serviços Industr de Utilidade Pública", "Construção Civil","Comércio", "Serviços","Adm. Pública", "Agro., extr. vegetal, caça e pesca"),

  Percentual=c(0.005,0.0399,0.001,0.024,0.3234,0.5769,0,0.028)
)

ggplot(SP, aes(x=Setores, y=Percentual)) +

  geom_bar(aes(fill = Setores), stat="identity") + theme_minimal()+

  coord_flip()+ scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+

  labs(title="Total percentual por setor do trabalho parcial em Minas") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(Percentual)),
              position = position_dodge(1),
              hjust = 0)
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, Jorge!!!